# Counting problem from Stanley's book

Tags: combinatorics

Let n be any positive integer. How many compositions can you find for n? I know this is not that hard, but I don't know how to give a combinatorial proof... This is another problem from Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics.

Comment: What is a composition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon, have you tried googling? There is even a Wikipedia page on the subject! There are lots of  standard terms, and we do not expect users of this site to document them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine $n$ rocks in line. Then every composition is equivalent to placing either one or zero stick in the empty space between rocks (do you see why?). Since you have $n-1$ empty spaces. You have $2^{n-1}$ possibilities.